# AWSMobileHubHelper sign-in with Facebook and Google can not build var cocoa pods

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, cocoapods

I have an iOS app install aws sdk , Facebook Login Kit and google login via cocoa pods. But when I build the app , xCode shows following error:

[Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vIkR.png)

I don't known what's wrong, I've follow mobile hub setup steps.

I've add

```
"-force_load $(SRCROOT)/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks/GoogleSignIn.framework/GoogleSignIn"
"-force_load $(SRCROOT)/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities"
```

to `Other Linker Flags`,

Here shows the pod file:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'AWSLogin' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'AWSS3'
    pod 'AWSCognito'
    pod 'AWSCognitoIdentityProvider'
    pod 'AWSDynamoDB'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.9'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.9'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.9'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
end
```

And I've add Add the frameworks AddressBook.framework, SafariServices.framework, and SystemConfiguration.framework as dependency.

Dose any body known why it can't build.

I posted the code [here](https://github.com/beeth0ven/AWSLogin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding two missing pods to the Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'AWSLogin' do
use_frameworks!
    pod 'AWSS3'
    pod 'AWSiOSSDKv2'
    pod 'AWSCognito'
    pod 'AWSCognitoIdentityProvider'
    pod 'AWSDynamoDB'
    pod 'AWSLambda'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.9'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.9'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.9'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
end
```